# Finding line break and carriage return (\r\n) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, select, carriage-return, line-breaks

I can't seem to find any info about this on the internet (or I'm just not looking in the right direction).

I have a few fields in my MySQL database containing a carriage return and line break \r\n .

Is there somebody who can tell me how to find them by using a query??

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "\r\n";
```

finds all records in `mytable` where `mycolumn` contains a `\r\n` sequence.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for answering! I had to slightly edit the query to `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "\r\n";` For some reason I only had to use single brackets..? Anyhow, it did the trick for me, thnx a lot!

Comment: Interesting - so the regex did not work with double backslashes, then?

Comment: No, it didn't... Removing one backslash did the trick for me.. I think it has something to do with the way the database was imported (a few weeks ago)... That possible??

Comment: At least in MySQL Workbench for Windows, when I used the `"` (double quote) from your answer, it was translated into a newline in my query and didn't work. I had to use `'` (single quotes.) I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: in some cases if you have \n and you can read that in the value of the column, and you can to find them, use  where x REGEXP '\\\\n'