# How can I add a break line in the where condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to include the newline in the `like` operator in my `where` condition. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_address_entity_text WHERE `value` LIKE '%%';
```

This is a sample string:

```
Ulica Srebrna

897
```

I have 2 new lines (break lines).  How can I build my query to have 2 break lines in the like operator condition?

Thank you

update:

[image]

Comment: `WHERE value REGEXP '\r\n\r\n';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding line break and carriage return (\r\n) in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997159/finding-line-break-and-carriage-return-r-n-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice solution using `REGEXP`, which is an enhanced version of `LIKE` supporting regex pattern matching:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_address_entity
WHERE value REGEXP '\n\n';
```

This would return all records having two continuous newlines (at least the Linux version).  You might also want to match for text on either side of the newlines.

Comment: ok, but i still have some string inside. This query returns me empty results, that's why I want to use the like operator

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?  If you have two newlines, the query should have returned something.  Is there any chance there is other whitespace between the newlines?

Comment: I'm on linux, you can see the pics that I attached to the post

Comment: @Chester The Linux newline is just `\n`, q.v. my updated answer.  If it still doesn't work, then you don't have two newlines adjacent in any record.

Comment: after 3 minutes , yes, will do :)