# Finding a column value with only a line break in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, line-breaks, control-characters

I have a MySQL DB table where a text column has some values which seem to be only CR and LF control characters (the value is just the line break).

I need a query which will identify all such rows. I tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "\r\n";
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997159/finding-line-break-and-carriage-return-r-n-in-mysql). But that didn't work. I guess I just need the correct regex in my case. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that your column contains `\r\n` and not `\n`?  Unless your data is Windows based, it won't contain the `\r` character

Answer (score 0):

I inserted a col with line breaks, i could retrieve it with foll SQL

```
mysql> select lat from TEST_INSERT where lat regexp '.*[\n]';
+--------------+
| lat          |
+--------------+
|  xx 
yy
zz

 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This returns rows where there are other characters besides the line break, I need to find the row which has ONLY the line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE col = "\r\n"
```

will check for that column having *only* a Windows-type line break.

```
WHERE col = "\n"
```

for unix-style.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for???

```
mysql> select lat from TEST_INSERT where lat regexp '^\n+$';
+-------+
| lat   |
+-------+
| 




 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```